# Raspberry pi Jessie: run source ~/.profile and workon cv at start-up

Tags: startup, .profile

I installed Raspbian Jessie on a Raspberry Pi 2 and then I added `virtualenv` and installed `python3` and `opencv3`. Now, I would like to make a python script runnable at start-up. Sometime ago, I had a Raspberry pi working without virtualenv and automatic start-up was easy, done via cron; in `crontab` I added a line to be triggered at reboot that started python with the script I needed.

Currently I need to do the following:

- start `~/.profile`
- workon cv
- python3 my_script.py

I tried to create a sh script containing the three lines here above. When running that sh, I have the message that `.profile` doesn't exist.

Here below the output of some tests:
I've created a sh called "start_monitoring.sh"containing the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This script is about to run another script."
source ~/.profile

# workon cv
# python3 monitoring_daemon.py -c conf.json
```

When running this sh from a SSH terminal using "bash ./start_monitoring.sh", I got this output

```
~$ bash ./start_monitoring.sh
```

This script is about to run another script.

```
: No such file or directory 3: /home/pi/.profile***
```

I don't understand why `.profile` is not found in this context.
What should I do?

Comment: If it needs to run at startup (not login), you could [write an `init.d` script](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/initscripts). You would have to have to manually set the environment instead of loading it from `~/.profile`.

Comment: There could be an automatic login, it's OK for me. The only constraint is to have an automatic start-up, without manual actions.

Answer (score 1):

If the virtual environmnet, you are going to run the script in, is created under user account (for example 'pi'), then crontab file has to be edited for the same user. You can check in terminal that the environment is located in home/pi/ and therefore created under 'pi' user:

```
$ cd ~/.virtualenvs
$ dir
```

If that is the case, then use following command to edit crontab:

```
$ crontab -e
```

In the first time, it creates crontab specifically for 'pi' user. If `$ sudo crontab -e` is used, then crontab is created for superuser and it will not activate the virtual environment.

My crontab command was following:

```
@reboot /home/pi/project_folder/autostart_script.sh >> /home/pi/project_folder/reboot.log 2>&1
```

autostart_script was like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/pi/.profile
workon environment_name
cd /home/pi/project_folder
python python_script.py
```

It is necessary to make it executable by the command in terminal:

```
$ chmod +x autostart_script.sh
```

Finally, python_script was just to log event:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
log_file = open("/home/pi/project_folder/log.txt", "w")
log_file.write(str(datetime.now()) + " :: " + "it is working")
log_file.close()
```

After reboot, it has to create two files in project_folder. Empty reboot.log and log.txt containing "it is working".

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a cron and I added some logs in order to understand this problem.

The cause is virtualenv is not usable as root because it has been created as a different user.

One solution is to run cron as the user that virtualenv work well with or activate the virtualenv by running:

. /home/pi/.virtualenvs//bin/activate

where  is the environment you want to enable.

Another solution (not yet confirmed) is to create a cron for the user able to use the virtualenv.

Hope this helps.

Kind regards,

Vlad